# Accessing Deadbolt user from within Controller

Tags: playframework-2.1, deadbolt

I am using **Deadbolt 2** with **Playframework 2.1**.

In the `getSubject()` function of my `DeadboltHandler` I check the user password and retrieve the user from the database.

Is it possible to access this user in my controllers to avoid retrieving the user twice per request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve, the developer of Deadbolt, suggested me the following:

> the trick is to store the user in the context, and then have your controller or deadbolt handler to access it.  This allows you to store the user by the actual class, and not have to use getSubject() and cast the resulting Subject to your actual User class.

So I decided to save the User object in the **args**-Field of **Http.Context.current()** and it works like a charm!

Comment: I'll make sure this is documented in the user guide : https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-guide

Comment: @SteveChaloner: is this already documented? I couldn't find it. And I don't understand how storing the user in the http context avoids casting? After all it is a simple (string -> object) map, so I must cast it to my concrete class, if I want to use it.

Comment: @SteveChaloner and what about Scala? There is no `Http.Context`